# Query relationship dates with eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am creating a calendar application with laravel as API.

I want to be able to search through activities (Activity model) and filter the months. So I have a search term **and** an array of certain months to filter by. 
This array looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'first_date' => '2016-03-11',
    'last_date' => '2016-03-31',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'first_date' => '2016-04-01',
    'last_date' => '2016-04-30',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'first_date' => '2016-05-01',
    'last_date' => '2016-05-31',
  )
  // etc...
)
```

An Activity has multiple CalendarItem(**s**) which represents the date**s** of an Activity.

Now I am not really sure what would be the best approach to get the Activity models between the dates of that array.

- I can raw query the CalendarItems and retrieve the Activities via their eloquent relationship, then I would have to sort out the duplicates.
- I can use whereHas('CalendarItem', function($q){ $q->whereBetween(etc..)})

Does anyone have a good suggestion?

**Edit 03/14/2014**
The relevant migrations look like this:
Activity migration:

```
 Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->unique();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('activitytype_id');
        $table->integer('course_leader')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

CalendarItem migration:

```
    Schema::create('calendar_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('activity_id')->references('id')->on('activities');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('starttime');
        $table->time('endtime');
    });
```

Comment: is this array a list of dates for different activities or are you saying one activity has multiple start and stop times and you want all results that fall in any of the dates?

Comment: Every calendaritem (belongs to one activity) has 1 date, a start time and a stop time.
I want to get activities that has a calendaritem between the start and stop dates given in the array.

Comment: There are no Activities that do not belong to a CalendarItem. The CalendarItems are the dates that belong to the Activities. 
In the end I want to add a function to the Activity model with a dates array parameter where I can feed it the array given above.

Comment: not sure what exactly u r after but for the first point u can use `unique()` so u wont have to deal with dups, or for the second point u can either use scopes or use `Accessors & Mutators.` but again it would be easier if u can include some code of how things should work

Comment: can you show the relevant migrations? does a calendar item have a field for start and end date? just one for date?

Comment: @tam: Just a date as you can now see in the migrations I added. I purposely just used 1 date to keep things relatively simple*.
*(and ofcourse because the business never asks for a date exceeding CalendarItem/ Activity).

Comment: what i meant to ask was: do all calendarItems belong to an activity? would it be sufficient to just query the `calendar_items` table without querying the activities table, or do you need need to first go through the activities table... meaning is the only reason you are not going through calendar_items because of duplicates?